# VBA to create pivot table without specific name

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I'm trying to create a macro that creates a pivot table in a separate tab. I would like to use this macro on a weekly basis with same structured data, but based in different sheets.

I tried using record macro - see the code generated below.
However, it looks like it hardcoded 1) source data and 2) the pivot name.

Is there a way to create a pivot that:

1. works on selected data, instead of set data range?
2. creates unique pivot names every time the macro is run?

Thanks, any help is much appreciated!

```
' test_macro Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "data sample!R1C1:R1048576C6", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
        :="data sample!R1C9", TableName:="PivotTable24", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("data sample").Select
    Cells(1, 9).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable24")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable24").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable24").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable24").PivotFields("Email")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable24").PivotFields("Email").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable24").PivotFields("group")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable24").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable24").PivotFields("logged in?"), "Sum of logged in?", xlSum
End Sub
```

Comment: I have always found this to be a handy reference for creating Pivot Tables...https://excelchamps.com/blog/vba-to-create-pivot-table/

Answer (score 0):

To work on selected data, you could use Selection address in R1C1 style, try this:

```
r = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
'use r in SourceData property. Example: "sheet1!R1C1:R10C10"
```

To create a unique name, you could just use current date and time, and replace special chars with "_". As long as you don't create two pivots in the same second, the name will be unique:

```
s = Replace(Replace(Replace(Now, " ", "_"), "/", "_"), ":", "_")
'use s in TableName property. Example: "26_01_2021_18_18_44"
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your advice!